# pfsense - slow connection to internet from wired network but not from wireless/wifi

Tags: wireless-networking, firewall, pfsense, internet-speed, wired

summary: internet speed tests indicate that the connection to the internet from my wired network is very slow, while speed tests from a device on my wifi network gets the expected (much faster) result.

I have pfsense configured with (what I think is) a normal, basic configuration.  It is connected directly to my cable modem and the LAN (2nd) port is connected to a switch for my wired network.  wifi is provided by a Belkin wifi router connected to the 3rd  ethernet port of the box running pfsense.  Noticing that web page loads were very slow, I run some internet speed tests from a computer on the wired network - with a very slow result - e.g.: 2.8mbps download and 0.47 upload.  I tried running speed tests from my pixel 5a phone, connected via the wifi router, and got the expected results (around 100mbps or better down, and around 20 mbps upload).  I plugged a laptop directly into the cable modem and, after it got an ip address via dhcp, ran a couple speed tests, also with the expected normal results.

Perhaps there's a misconfiguration in pfsense causing this, but I have no idea where to look (not being very experienced with  firewalls).  However, until today I have not noticed any problems with slow web page loading - so it seems that something has changed, but I've not touched the pfsense config. for several days.

This is, for me, quite a puzzle.  Any ideas on where to look to try to solve it would be appreciated.

Comment: Are the 2nd and 3rd Ethernet ports assigned to separate pfSense "interfaces" (and if so, do they have separate IP subnets), or are they bridged into one interface? Do you have the same issues if you swap the LAN connection to port 3 and Belkin to port 2?

Comment: They're on separate subnets - not bridged. And thanks much for your suggestion - it led me to the solution.  Before trying the exchange you suggested, I tried connecting a laptop directly to the "slow" port (2) and ran the speed test again, which was fast/normal.  I then tried with the switch that was being used and that was normal!  So, apparently, it was the cable that was causing the problem.  I'm relieved to know the fault was not with the router.